# Jenkins does not start properly after reboot on GCE

Tags: java, jenkins, google-compute-engine, bitnami

If I need to restart Jenkins due to installing a plugin for instance the slaves are never turned on. I am using Google Compute Engine. I followed this tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy

Using this to create the Jenkins server:

```
export PASSWORD=<password>
export PROJECT_ID=<project-id>

gcloud compute \
    instances create bitnami-jenkins \
    --project ${PROJECT_ID} \
    --image-project bitnami-launchpad \
    --image bitnami-jenkins-1-587-0-linux-debian-7-x86-64-image \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --metadata "bitnami-base-password=${PASSWORD}" \
               "bitnami-default-user=user" \
               "bitnami-key=jenkins" \
               "bitnami-name=Jenkins" \
               "bitnami-version=1-587-0" \
               "bitnami-url=//bitnami.com/stack/jenkins" \
               "bitnami-description=Jenkins." \
               "startup-script-url=https://dl.google.com/dl/jenkins/p2dsetup/setup-script.sh" \
    --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" \
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control" \
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting" \
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin" \
    --tags "bitnami-launchpad"
```

Here is an image of how Jenkins look after restart:

[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem. It's been time since you posted the question. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

We just released changes to the startup script to fix this problem.  Next time you restart the instance your slaves should be online.

Comment: Hi Nghia, it seems the problem still happening. I tried with a fresh push to deploy configuration and, after instance reboot, the slaves continued offline

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with making it work on Debian image.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu
does not work.

I then tried Centos image `centos-7-v20220406`, and followed the instructions below. This worked. Note that you might have to install wget before starting with the steps below.

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo \
    https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
sudo yum upgrade
# Add required dependencies for the jenkins package
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```